# Close the media-upload thickbox right after upload is finished?

Tags: uploads, javascript, front-end

I'm working on a front-end uploader using WP's own media-uploading functions. All is well, except that I just want to simplify some UI things, like removing tabs and unnecessary information for my users. Most importantly, I'd like to magically close the Upload Thickbox once the uploads are done and the files are crunched.

I'm aware of the `add_attachment` hook and I'm already using it to do some ImageMagick handling, but it fires every time a file is uploaded, so this is kind of too much.

Seaching through core, I got to [wp-includes/js/swfupload/handlers.dev.js](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.4.1/wp-includes/js/swfupload/handlers.dev.js#L232) and around line 232 there's this:

```
function uploadComplete(fileObj) {
    // If no more uploads queued, enable the submit button
    if ( swfu.getStats().files_queued == 0 ) {
        jQuery('#cancel-upload').prop('disabled', true);
        jQuery('#insert-gallery').prop('disabled', false);
    }
}
```

This is precisely where I want to hook so that, instead of enabling the submit button, I'd just fire `TB_close()`.

Can this be done in any way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was solved as simply as:

1. Hooking a custom .js script to the media-upload thickbox, so that it runs inside the iFrame:

   ```
   function admin_styles_scripts_media_upload() {
       wp_register_script('mediajs', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/button.js', array('jquery'), true);
       wp_enqueue_script('mediajs');

   }
   add_action('admin_print_scripts-media-upload-popup','admin_styles_scripts_media_upload');
   ?>
   ```
2. Use the script to replace the default Save button with a custom one, and call `self.parent.tb_remove` from that:

   ```
   jQuery(document).ready(function() {

       jQuery('<a href="#" id="back_to_admin" class="button">Voltar para Edição</a>').insertAfter('.ml-submit');   
       jQuery('.savebutton.ml-submit').detach();
       jQuery('a.toggle').live("remove");

       jQuery('#back_to_admin').live('click',function() {

           parent.uploadedImages();
           self.parent.tb_remove();

   });

   });
   ```